# In Die2Nite, how do you mix pharmaceutical products?

Tags: die2nite

I've read on some wikis that if you mix two pharmaceutical products, you can create a random drug. But I can't figure out how to mix them. When I'm in my house I see the option to "Use" the Pharmaceutical product, but that shows up even if I only have one, and I believe all that will do is make me take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't take pharmaceutical products, only mix them. If you have two, click Use to combine the two pharmaceutical products. If you try it with one, nothing will happen.

Comment: Thanks. I'd been avoiding hitting "Use" since I saw at as an option even when I had just one. I was afraid I'd hurt myself. It's what did the trick, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must have two Pharms.  Also remember that when you mix the Pharms, you don't always get a random drug, and that if you have the Labratory then it improves your chances of a getting a better drug.